# Is there a way to tell if a wired headset is connected to phone

Tags: android

Is there a programmatic way to tell if a wired headset (not bluetooth) is connected to a phone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell if a wired headset is in use with [AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn%28%29).

You can also listen for the broadcast action [ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: +1 for AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() - I hadn't discovered that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a BroadcastReceiver and have it listen for the `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` Intent action.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [this code](http://android.bigresource.com/Track/android-RWgBjiZi6/):

```
Intent intent = registerReceiver(myHandler,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)); 
if (intent != null) 
            myHandler.onReceive(this, intent);
```

I hope this helps